# (imutils) PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Tags: python, conda, imutils

I'm using python 3.7 and trying to install `imutils` package in conda by the following:

```
conda install imutils
conda install -c mlgill imutils=0.5.4
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 imutils=0.5.4
conda install -c conda-forge imutils
```

They all generate the same error:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - imutils

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

unless:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imutils
```

Generates:

```
InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7
```

Comment: Works for me (`conda search conda-forge::imutils[subdir=linux-64,version=0.5.4]`). Instead of `https://repo.continuum.io/` my channels start with either `https://repo.anaconda.org` or `https://conda.anaconda.org`.  What does `conda config --show channel_alias` report?

Comment: @merv report this: channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org

Comment: @merv 
`Name                       Version                   Build  Channel        
imutils                    0.5.4            py36h5fab9bb_0  conda-forge    
imutils                    0.5.4            py36hd000896_0  conda-forge    
imutils                    0.5.4            py37h89c1867_0  conda-forge    
imutils                    0.5.4            py38h578d9bd_0  conda-forge    
imutils                    0.5.4            py39hf3d152e_0  conda-forge`

Comment: You changed the error. The new one you show implies that your `conda` package is outdated. You need to run `conda update -n base conda`

Comment: @merv I don't have permissions to update conda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imutils library is a non-conda package. I have installed it by `pip`

```
pip install imutils
```

Reference:

https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/issues/24#issuecomment-359399161